# Ormlite H2 error assigning data from class

Tags: java, orm, ormlite

I'm having hard times understanding a Ormlite error log.
I have the following bean:

```java
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "users")
public class UserBean {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField(unique = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = UserKeys.Constants.mail_value)
    private String mail;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = UserKeys.Constants.password_value)
    private String password;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = UserKeys.Constants.name_value)
    private String name;

    public UserBean() {

    }

    public UserBean(String mail, String pwd) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = pwd;
    }

   /** getter and setters here **/
}
```

and in my main:

```java
UserBean foo = new UserBean("foo@gmail.com", "asd");
UserBean bar = new UserBean("bar@gmail.com", "asd");
usersDao.create(foo);
```

After the create method, I get the following error log:

```
[main] ERROR com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType - assiging from data class it.myapi.model.beans.UserBean, val class java.lang.Integer: 1
```

However, it's not blocking: the application actually works and the data are correctly persisted.
This is a quite annoying log and I don't understand the root cause: do you have any idea about how to solve the problem?

I'm using Ormlite version 5.0-SNAPSHOT

Thank you

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [main] ERROR com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType - assiging from data class it.myapi.model.beans.UserBean, val class java.lang.Integer: 1

Ha!  I *just* found and removed an improper log message that got checked into the source tree a couple of days ago.  It should have been `logger.trace(...)` and certainly not error.

See [this commit on github](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/40e14866dcc377f7aa5654c609c42946ef20c8ab).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So to avoid this error should I compile locally the project from github? Do you have any plan for the 5.x release fixing it?

Comment: Trying hard to push for 5.X release by the end of June.  It will be fixed there.